# 'npm run build' by webpack, I got an error...help me

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, transpiler

I got following error when I was transpiling the webpack.

```
**error message** 
$ npm run build

> webpack

Hash: d3c6c864b2d5118a08d7
Version: webpack 4.8.3
Time: 399ms
Built at: 2018-06-04 20:51:32
 1 asset
Entrypoint main = bundle.js
[0] ./src/index.js 249 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import App from "../component/chatapp";
|
| ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
|
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html
    [0] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 519 bytes {0} [built]
    [1] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
        + 2 hidden modules
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! website@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the website@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\bca19\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-04T11_51_32_160Z-debug.log
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
    const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
 entry: path.resolve(path.resolve(__dirname, "src"), "index.js"),
 output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
  filename: 'bundle.js'
 },
 mode: 'production',
 resolve: {
  extensions: ['js', '.jsx']
 },
 module: {
  rules: [{
   test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
   loader: "babel-loader",
   include: [
    path.resolve(__dirname + "component"),
    path.resolve(__dirname + "src")
   ],
   exclude: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")
   ],
   query: {
    presets: ["react", "es2015"]
   }
  }, {
   test: /\.css$/,
   use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    use: "css-loader"
   })
  }, {
   test: /\.scss$/,
   use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    use: [
      "css-loader",
      "sass-loader"
     ]
   })
  }]
 },
 plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
   title: "광talk",
   filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "public", "index.html")
  })
 ],
 devtool: "inline-source-map",
 devServer: {
  contenBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
  compress: true,
  port: 3000
 }
};
```

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test website",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.8.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4",
    "zombie": "^6.1.2"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015"
    ]
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "../component/chatapp";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**chatapp.js**

```js
import React from "react";

class ChatApp extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <div>mission success</div>
  );
 }
}
export default ChatApp;
```

I don't know why my codes are not working.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the path of the rule is wrong.Try
`include: [
                path.resolve(__dirname , "component"),
                path.resolve(__dirname ,"src")
            ],`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a dot before the file extension.

```
extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
```

Comment: thanks for your commnent. i fixed  that. but i still got that error